# How to disable particular check box cell in a DataGridView CheckBox column

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a winForm with a DataGridView control. It contains 5 columns, one of them is a CheckBox column. I want to enable/disable checkbox cell of this column based on the value present in another column at the same row.

I can disable entire column using [DisabledCheckBoxCell](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31829/Disabled-Checkbox-Column-in-the-DataGridView&ei=djKZT5eLDIOurAe4poTJAQ&usg=AFQjCNFnPfSO8hWsGNiMsLO9DZSo28NFvg&sig2=w-EZ6lMy-L6STIiFYbJdMQ)

But it makes entire column in disabled state.

Here is a snippet of DataGridView,

SourceColumn  | DestinationColumn 
true                                | enabled

true                                | enabled
false                              | disabled

Does anyone have idea, how this can be achieved in .Net.

Answer (score 25):

Vijay,

DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn does not have property called disabled so by changing the style of the checkbox you can make it look like as if it is disabled. Look at the following code.

```
 private void dataGridView1_RowPostPaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex == 1)
        {
            DataGridViewCell cell=dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0];
            DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chkCell = cell as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;
            chkCell.Value = false;
            chkCell.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
            chkCell.Style.ForeColor = Color.DarkGray;
            cell.ReadOnly = true;

        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is working with some minor issues. I have checkbox cells in column headers as well. This is affecting them too. When I switch to other App and return to the original App, UI looks distorted.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up doing something like this to get an actual disabled checkbox to show up:

```
using System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles;

public partial class YourForm : Form
{

    private static readonly VisualStyleRenderer DisabledCheckBoxRenderer;

    static YourForm()
    {
        DisabledCheckBoxRenderer = new VisualStyleRenderer(VisualStyleElement.Button.CheckBox.UncheckedDisabled);
    }

    private void dataGridView_RowPostPaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex > -1)
        {
            int checkBoxColumnIndex = this.yourCheckBoxColumn.Index;
            var checkCell = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)this.dataGridView[checkBoxColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];
            var bounds = this.dataGridView.GetCellDisplayRectangle(checkBoxColumnIndex , e.RowIndex, false);

            // i was drawing a disabled checkbox if i had set the cell to read only
            if (checkCell.ReadOnly)
            {
                const int CheckBoxWidth = 16;
                const int CheckBoxHeight = 16;

                // not taking into consideration any cell style paddings
                bounds.X += (bounds.Width - CheckBoxWidth) / 2;
                bounds.Y += (bounds.Height - CheckBoxHeight) / 2;
                bounds.Width = CheckBoxWidth;
                bounds.Height = CheckBoxHeight;

                if (VisualStyleRenderer.IsSupported)
                {

                    // the typical way the checkbox will be drawn
                    DisabledCheckBoxRenderer.DrawBackground(e.Graphics, bounds);
                }
                else
                {

                    // this method is only drawn if the visual styles of the application
                    // are turned off (this is for full support)
                    ControlPaint.DrawCheckBox(e.Graphics, bounds, ButtonState.Inactive);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using RowDataBound event for your GridView. You can cast eventargs to row, find control on this row and disable it.
This event fires for each row of gridview, even for headers and footers, so try not to catch exception.
Here is some code might be useful to you

```
protected void xxx_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.Row != null) && e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
```

Comment: I want to disable the cell in respective row, I could not find enabled property on a Cell. I am using RowPostPaint event.

Comment: I am afraid there may not be any function to disable an individual cell, but you can do something while the cell is clicked, for example to revert the value for the cell you wan to disable

Comment: Yes I tried that as well on CellEndEdit event, but it is not respected. The check box still shows the current state ( checked/unchecked).

Comment: @Johnny_D yes, it is a WinForm application.

Answer (score -1):

```
         foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
         {
             var cell = dataGridView1[cellindex, row.Index];
             if (cell.Value != null )
                 if((bool)cell.Value == true)
             {
               ....
             }
         }
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, Code only answers tend to be frowned upon, so please add some explanation as to what your code does and why it is an apt solution for this problem (even if how the code runs seems obvious to you)