# How to set color for checkbox present in datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, datagridview, datagridviewcheckboxcell

I have a datagridview in windows form. It looks like this.

[image]

In this, have one Checkbox column, two textbox column.

My requirement is need to set readonly true and set grey color for the checkbox for the country has Germany as like below.

[image]

Not like below

[image]

I need to set color for checkbox only not for datagridview cell.

Is anyone have idea for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Background colour of DataGridViewCheckboxCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660337/background-colour-of-datagridviewcheckboxcell)

Comment: @sawsine - This is for datagridview cell. I need a color only for checkbox.

Comment: hmm, what about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7664115/c-sharp-datagridviewcheckboxcolumn-hide-gray-out

Comment: [How to disable a checkbox column on clicking of another checkbox column in DatagridView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16996901/7444103) (bad title, consider the answer alone) -> You need only the `CellPainting` event. You can change the condition shown there in, e.g., `var dgv = sender as DataGridView; var cell = dgv[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex]; if (cell is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell && cell.ReadOnly) {  bool value = e.Value is null ? false : (bool)e.Value; //[...] }`. In the `CheckBoxRenderer` method, you have to add `-1`  to both measures of the Point position, because it's off by 1 pixel.

Answer (score 1):

Given the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10356938/5509738) and slightly change it

```
private void DataGridView1_RowPostPaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs e)
{
    var value = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value);
    DataGridViewCell cell = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0];

    if (value == "Germany" && cell.ReadOnly != true)
    {
        DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chkCell = cell as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;
        chkCell.Value = false;
        chkCell.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
        chkCell.Style.ForeColor = Color.DarkGray;
        cell.ReadOnly = true;
    }
}
```

Result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by setting checkbox's property: 'Enabled' as false.
by that way, the checkbox cannot be clicked and its color changes automatically to grey.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSL6L.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).